# Invalid argument raise exception

Tags: python, class, exception, parameters

How do I test my parameter if it will raise an exception without actually raising it, using `try` and `except`?

```
class MyClass:
    def function(parameter):
        pass
```

`parameter` is an ambiguous function that may raise 1 or more of any exception, for example:

```
parameter = pow("5", 5)
```

A `TypeError` is raised as soon as the function is called and before the function can execute its statements.

Comment: Why don't you want to use try ... except? Just for curiosity or is there any other reason?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I do want to use `try` and `except`, but I don't know how it would work in the parameters.

Comment: What your parameter will raise depends on how your function is implemented. In your example I don't see how `parameter` could raise an exception inside `function`.

Comment: If `parameter` is invalid it will raise an exception as soon as it is called. I want to be able to "catch" the exception with `try` and `except`. I do not have any information on what `parameter` will be except that it is a function and will raise any exception.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of this. What do you mean by `parameter` being invalid? What do you mean by "it might/will raise an exception"? Values don't raise exceptions, **operations** do. You have to try to **do something** with the parameter for any problem to occur.

Comment: `def x(a): pass`, when calling `x(pow("5", 5))` a TypeError is automatically raised.

Comment: You should put this code example into your question, the exception is not raised inside your function. I imagined you were doing somthing like that, take a look at my answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment to another answer you said: *"`parameter` is another function; take for example: `parameter = pow("5", 5)` which raises a `TypeError`, but it could be any type of function and any type of exception."*

If you want to catch the exeption inside your function you have to call the paramenter (which I'm assuming is callable) inside that function:

```
def function(callable, args=()):
    try:
        callable(*args)
    except:
        print('Ops!')
```

Example:

```
>>> function(pow, args=("5", 5))
Ops!
```

This is if you really need to call your "paramenter" inside the function. Otherwise your should manage its behaviour outside, maybe with something like:

```
>>> try:
...     param = pow('5', 5)
... except:
...     param = 10
... 
>>> param
10
>>> function(param)
```

In this example, to raise an exception is `pow` not `function`, so it's a good practice to separate the the two different call, and wrap with a `try-except` statement the code that might fail.

Comment: What if `parameter` was just a function without any parameters itself?

Comment: @ChristopherM: If `parameter` is a function that does not require any argument then just call `function(parameter)` becaue by default `args=()`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you want to handle the exceptions raised and also inspect what sort of errors were raised for further inspection? Here is one way of doing it.

```
class Foo(object):
    def find_errors(arg):
        errors = []
        try:
            # do something
        except TypeError as e:
            errors.append(e)
            # handle exception somehow
        except ValueError as e:
            errors.append(e)
            # handle exception somehow
        # and so on ...
        finally:
            pass #something here

        return errors, ans
```

Now you can inspect `errors` and find out what exceptions have been raised.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the parameter to be a certain type, you can use `type(paramter) is parametertype`.

For example, if you wanted to verify that 'i' is an int, run instructions `if(type(i) is int):`

By edit:

```
try:
    pow("5",5)
    return 0
except Exception, err:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s\n' % str(err))
    return 1
```

Comment: I need to be able to count the number of exceptions raised by `parameter` without actually raising one.

Comment: What type is the parameter? Or is it the function you are testing for error throwing, and not the parameter?

Comment: If you put at the beginning of your function `if(type(parameter) is int)` and return if it is not the correct type, then your problem is solved. If I understand the problem.

Comment: `parameter` is another function; take for example: `parameter = pow("5", 5)` which raises a TypeError, but it could be any type of function and any type of exception.

Comment: You can actually use a `try/except` to catch any type of exception. For example, see the edits to the comment above (code blocks are hard to type in comments)

Comment: Should I make a helper function to test `parameter` first? I just wanted to know if there was a more Pythonic method of doing this.

Comment: That would probably be best. I'm not a python expert, though.

It honestly seems like, if you're going to run `parameter` anyway, that you don't need a helper function, and that you can just try to run parameter outright. If you `catch` an `exception`, exit the function.

I don't know the nature of what you're doing, though, so a helper function may be the better alternative.

Comment: @user1131435: Don't test using `type()`. What if you have a subclass of `int`? It will then fail. Instead, `try` the operation, and handle an error then. Duck-typing FTW.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a helper function just wont do, how can I call `try` within `(parameter)`? :S

Comment: Wrap the function call of `function()` with `try`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you mean is how to catch the `TypeError` exceptions caused by invalid function calls?

Like this:

```
def foo(bar):
    pass

foo(1, 2)
```

You don't catch them in the function and certainly not in the `def foo(bar):` line.

It's the *caller* of the function that made an error so that's where you catch the exception:

```
try:
    foo(1, 2)
except TypeError:
    print('call failed')
```